# ERROR error: The theme directory "nameOfTheme" does not exist

Tags: wordpress

I sature of Wordpress as soon as I solve a beug, shortly after I have another !!!

I want to select my theme.
Now, here I am with a new ERROR error: The theme directory "nameOfTheme" does not exist. In my wp-admin / themes.php

However my content / themes has a folder nameOfTheme! Besides I also have the theme twentyseventeen, but it does not appear.
When I want to reinstall it via: Themes add new, I have a login window info, which requests info hostname, FTP username, FTP password and 
I do not have them

The site is under trial so not hosted

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you checked folder permissions on your server? What is inside the `nameOfTheme` folder, is it empty? How do you upload your files if not via FTP at the moment? Use that same method and upload the files directly to the folder